# How to use LIMIT and IN together to have a default row in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am exploring SQL with W3School [page](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_limit) and I have this requirements where I need to limit the query to a certain number but also having a default row included with that limit.

[image]

Here I want a default row where the customer name is Alfreds, then grab the remaining 29 rows to complete the query regardless of what their name is.

[image]

I tried to look on other SO question but they are too complicated to understand and using different syntax.

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: screen shots are inaccessible. Please post the information as text.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a specific order clause.
Try this

`SELECT * FROM Customers order by (case when CustomerName in ('Alfreds Futterkiste') then 0 else CustomerId end) limit 30 ;`

Comment: what is `then 0` is it the index of row?

Comment: What is the main difference of this answer from Barmar answer? Sorry I am noob at RDB

Comment: I am assumin CustomerId to be unique and non 0 
Hence to make Alfreds Futterkiste appear on top and display 29 others I am just giving it a number 0 in order by clause to make sure it appears on top.

Comment: Thanks that is what I needed as well for the default to be always on top.

Comment: Barmar's answer doesnt make sure you get 30 elements everytime.
Case 1:  What if there is no 'Alfreds Futterkiste' in your table? it will give you 29 rows results and not 30.
Case 2: What if there are more than 1 'Alfreds Futterkiste' in your table? It will give you 29+(Total Number of 'Alfreds Futterkiste') as a result, it won't be exactly 30 results.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that the column I will be actually using will have a unique value just like a PK and being indexed thus it is guaranteed of no duplication.

Comment: Will this work fine if the table is empty at first?

Comment: Yes it will. Queries are crazy beautiful. Will give you result if there is no syntax error

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS, please do accept the answer if it helped. Trying for a job here, would help with the reputations :)

Comment: One more question, how about when I added another argument inside the `IN` operator? What will be the order of the item now?

Comment: They both will appear on top and the remaining 28 will follow

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` to combine the two queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName != 'Alfredo Futterkiste'
LIMIT 9
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerName = 'Alfreo Futterkiste'
```

Comment: Note for OP it would perhaps be better to use the PK, rather than the name, in the WHERE if there may be more than one Alfredo Futterkiste in the table

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks that makes sense, however in my actual application the column I will be using would be unique like a PK.

Comment: Is it indexed? Better to search on the PK if it is not (and don't index it just for this purpose when one could search in PK; index maintenance has a cost too)

Comment: Yes the column I will be using is indexed.

Comment: @CaiusJard the PK in my case is a string coming from an API in which I do not have control and cannot anticipate its value. But yeah maybe I could actually just copy it and statically define it in my query thus I could say `id = 'static_value'`, to be more optimize.

Comment: @CaiusJard The principle is the same regardless of the column being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have a default row in SQL you should really have that row in the table with a known primary key, and then UNION it onto your query:

```
--default row, that is always included as long as the table has a PK 1
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerId = 1

UNION ALL
 
--other rows, a variable number of
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerId <> 1 AND ...

LIMIT 30
```

The limit presented in this way applies to the result of the Union

If you ever want to do something where you're unioning together limited sets in other combinations you might want to look at eg a form like

```
(... LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(... LIMIT 28)
```